# Get width and height of Image app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
BlobKey bk = currentProfile.getProfileBlobKey();
Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(bk);
Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(500, 500);
Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, oldImage);
int imageWidth = newImage.getWidth();
int imageHeight = newImage.getHeight();
```

This code doesn't seem to work since `ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(bk);` doesn't return a real Image.  Does anyone know a workaround for this? This seems to be the expected behavior.  This issue is discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4757) but they don't have a solution for getting the height and width just the byte[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile blobFile = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey);
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(blobFile, false);
byte[] imageData = getBytes(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel));
Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(imageData);
// now you have the real Image
```

and this little snippet for reading an input stream:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int len;
    byte[] data = new byte[10000];
    while ((len = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, len);
    }

    buffer.flush();
    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the ImageReader Class?

Comment: no, is there any good documentation, having trouble finding any